# Hash table Get_Item returning blank line - Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

```
$searchterm = read-host “Enter search term for uninstallers”
$uninstallers = get-childitem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
$founditems = $uninstallers | ? {(Get-ItemProperty -path (“HKLM:\”+$_.name) -name Displayname -erroraction silentlycontinue) -match $searchterm}
write-host “Searched registry for uninstall information on $searchterm”
write-host “——————————————”
$x = 0
$uninstallcommandtable = @{}
$uninstalldisplaytable = @{}
if ($founditems -eq $null) {“None found”} else {
    write-host “Found “($founditems | measure-object).count” item(s):`n”
    $founditems | % {
        $x = $x + 1
        Write-host "Item: $x"
        Write-host “Displayname: “$_.getvalue(“Displayname”)
        Write-host “Displayversion: “$_.getvalue(“Displayversion”)
        Write-host “InstallDate: “$_.getvalue(“InstallDate”)
        Write-host “InstallSource: “$_.getvalue(“InstallSource”)
        Write-host “UninstallString: “$_.getvalue(“UninstallString”)
    $uninstallcommandtable.Add($x, $_.getvalue(“UninstallString”))
    $uninstalldisplaytable.Add($x, $_.getvalue(“Displayname”))
        Write-host “`n”
    }
}

Write-host ($uninstalldisplaytable | Out-String)
$whichprogram = read-host "Which program do you want to uninstall?"
Write-host ($uninstallcommandtable.Get_Item($whichprogram) | Out-String)
```

For some reason the last Write-host is returning a blank line. I verified with a test output just before the last read-host, so I know the $uninstallcommandtable is proper. Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your hashtable Names are type `System.Int32`. This will show you that:

```
$uninstallcommandtable.Keys | % {$_.GetType().FullName}
```

`Read-Host` is setting a variable of type `System.String`. So you will need to convert the string to an `System.Int32` like this:

```
Write-host $uninstallcommandtable.Get_Item([Int32] $whichprogram)
```

You can also use:

```
Write-host $uninstallcommandtable.Item([Int32] $whichprogram)
```

Comment: Andy, excellent. Worked perfectly. Now to break this script more by adding more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can make the key a string when you create the hash entry:

```
$uninstallcommandtable.Add("$x", $_.getvalue(“UninstallString”))
```

Comment: mjolinor, thanks I will add this in as a comment so I remember all the ways to do it.